# fmod returning incorrect result

Tags: php, floating-point, fmod

Why does PHP's fmod function not work as intended. Am I missing something?

```
fmod(2.0, 0.1); // outputs 0.1
```

The following should output 0 since 2.0/0.1 = 20 and therefore has no remainder. I'm aware of floating point math errors, but this function is specifically made for floating point numbers, so I'm not sure why it would return an incorrect result.

Comment: It is a float inaccuracy error, and as this function works with IEEE754 floats it's quite susceptible to it.... and it makes absolutely no difference that it's "specifically made for floating point numbers".... that potential inaccuracy is still there

Comment: Take a look at [bcmod](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bcmod.php) instead.

Comment: `0.1` is not exactly representable in any of the IEEE-754 binary floating-point formats. So the division will not be exact, and the remainder will *not* be zero. If the floating-point number closest to `0.1` is slightly larger than the true mathematical value, you will see the observed behavior, as the integral portion of the quotient will be 19, not 20.

Comment: @MarkBaker that makes sense. It's just strange that the php docs are specifically calling a floating point function without making any mention that the function won't work as intended in many cases. I found a solution [further down the page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fmod.php#48881). It will probably not provide bank-grade precision, but in my situation it's not necessary.

Comment: @vascowhite unfortunately bcmod doesn't work with floats. It will always return 0 or a Division by zero error for decimals less than 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest IEEE 754 64-bit binary number to 0.1 is 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. 20 times that is bigger than 2.0. 19 times it is less, with remainder 0.0999999999999998667732370449812151491641998291015625. Depending on how you are printing that remainder it could come out as "0.1".

The key here is that `fmod` did **exactly** what it was supposed to do, given the actual inputs 2.0 and 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. The inability to exactly represent 0.1 is a well known consequence of binary floating point.